# How to verify `pallet-identity` identities via signature

Tags: smart-contract, identity, pallet-identity

I'm considering using an identity service such as `pallet-identity` in my smart contract and would like to know if it's possible to verify an attestation that has been judged on `pallet-identity` such as: `email: example@example.com` via a signature or any other means accessible via a smart contract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pallet-identity` currently doesn't require an explicit signature of an identity. The signature is implicit because the registrar signs the entire `Call` that provides the judgment.
However, from a smart contract on the same chain you should be able to check an identity by calling into the chain to ensure that the identity is confirmed.